# Expo notification doesn't show on physical device

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to add notification to my react native app but I have encountered a problem.

When I am running the app on expo go and trying to send notifications to my Iphone 12 it does not receive them. I am getting a pushToken correctly and the response show status ok but I still does not see the notification on my phone.

I have tried both sending the notification through the app and through my flask python backend.

my react native code:

```
  registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    if (Device.isDevice) {
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
            finalStatus = status;
        }
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
            return;
        }
        const token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
        this.setState({ expoPushToken: token });
        this.sendPushNotification()
    } else {
        alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
    }
  
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
            name: 'default',
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
        });
    }
    
};

 sendPushNotification = async () => {
    if (this.state.expoPushToken != '') {
        console.log(this.state.expoPushToken)
        const message = {
            to: this.state.expoPushToken,
            sound: 'default',
            title: 'Original Title',
            body: 'And here is the body!',
            data: { someData: 'goes here' },
        };
  
        await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(message),
        });
    }
  }
```

My python code:

```
def send_push_message(message, db, extra=None):
    db.execute("SELECT pushtoken FROM users WHERE user_id = %s", (session["user_id"],))
    pushToken = db.fetchone()
    
    if pushToken is not None and pushToken[0] != '':
        try:
            response = PushClient().publish(
                PushMessage(to=pushToken[0],
                            title=message,
                            body=message,
                            data=extra))
            print(response)
            return True
        except:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

The response I am getting:

```
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "id": "e16239ff-3db0-47d9-abb1-eb47ba636baa",
    "status": "ok",
  },
}
```